# Why does .Sum("B2:F2") generate "Unable to get the Property of the WorksheetFunction class" error?

Tags: excel, vba

Even when I try to sum a row of values. I tried `worksheetfunction.mmult` but I get the same error. Do I need to add more references to my Excel?

```
Sub GetObj()
Dim Obj As Double
Dim VB1, VB2, AESum As Double
Dim range1, range2, cell1, cell2 As Range

With Worksheets("Result")
    AESum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum("B2:F2")
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On it's own `"B2:F2"` is just a string. If you want to use it as a range then you will have to specifically specify that.

Change

```
AESum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum("B2:F2")
```

to

```
AESum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("B2:F2"))
```

Comment: Beat me by a few secs! The disadvantage of answering from a mobile... :-)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum("B2:F2")` use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("B2:F2"))`!

Answer (score 1):

You can change

```
AESum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum("B2:F2")
```

to

```
AESum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("B2:F2"))
```

you could also evaluate the expression as:

```
AESum = [Sum(Result!B2:F2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("J7:J8"))
```

this works for me!

Comment: this weirdly answers the question about 4 years later and with no additional info -also the range doesn't correspond to the OP's question. no downvote from me but just curious as to what purpose this serves ;)